# Filling green color to matched values and red color to different values in two sheets of same excel file

Tags: excel, vba, background-color, difference

I want to fill green color if value is same in both files (Sheet1 and Sheet1_Compare), if not matched fill with red color. And Excel file contains multiple sheets with their comparison sheets in same excel.
Cover sheet and revision sheet should be excluded.

```
 Public Sub Differentiate()

     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim wsRow As Integer
     Dim wsCol As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim j As Integer


    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Cover Sheet" Or ws.Name <> "Revision Sheet" Then
            If InStr(LCase(ws.Name), LCase("Compared")) = 0 Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                wsRow = .Rows.Count
                wsCol = .Columns.Count
            End With
            for i = 1 To wsRow
                for j = 1 To wsCol
                If Sheets(ws).Cells(i,j) = Sheet(ws + "_Compare").Cells(i,j) Then
                    Sheets(ws).Cells(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'Green
                    Sheets(ws + "_Compare").Cells(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'Green
                Else
                    Sheets(ws).Cells(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
                    Sheets(ws + "_Compare").Cells(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
                End If
                Next j
            Next i
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    End Sub
```

Comment: It would be easier to follow this guide than to use VBA; https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/identifying-duplicate-values-in-an-excel-list

Comment: Your code seems okay. what problem are you facing?

Comment: @NaveenArora i have given references to MS excel also.
'Compile error:
Sub or Function not defined.'

Comment: @Mech  I want to make macro that works on every sheet within the same excel file and do the above work.
Conditional formatting i know, but that is manual task and time taking also, if we have too many sheets to compare.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Check the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes. It should work.

1. As you are comparing against `"_Compare"` sheets so you should exclude these sheets from loop.

   Change this: `If ws.Name <> "Cover Sheet" Or ws.Name <> "Revision Sheet"`
   to

   `If ws.Name <> "Cover Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Revision Sheet" And Not (ws.Name Like "*_Compare")`
2. Change `Sheets(ws)` to `Sheets(ws.Name)`
3. Change `Sheet(ws + "_Compare")` to `Sheets(ws.Name + "_Compare")`

Edited Code:

```
 Public Sub Differentiate()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wsRow As Integer
 Dim wsCol As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Cover Sheet" And ws.Name <> "Revision Sheet" And Not (ws.Name Like "*_Compare") Then
        If InStr(LCase(ws.Name), LCase("Compared")) = 0 Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                wsRow = .Rows.Count
                wsCol = .Columns.Count
            End With
            For i = 1 To wsRow
                For j = 1 To wsCol
                    If Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(i, j) = Sheets(ws.Name + "_Compare").Cells(i, j) Then
                        Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'Green
                        Sheets(ws.Name + "_Compare").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'Green
                    Else
                        Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
                        Sheets(ws.Name + "_Compare").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        End If
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Code to check if the sheet exists or not.

```
Option Explicit

Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
Dim Sht As Worksheet

    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Application.Proper(Sht.Name) = Application.Proper(WorksheetName) Then
            WorksheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sht
WorksheetExists = False
End Function
```

Then Call the above function in following way:

```
MsgBox WorksheetExists("Sheet1_Compare")
```

Comment: Thanks for it.
Can we add one more condition that, if this excel file doesn't contain _compare sheets then we will show a message or prompt.
because right now it is generating system generated error : runtime error '9' subscript out of range